# How to end a phone call on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'd like to find a way to end a phone call on Windows Phone automatically. For example, after one hour of call, the app, no matter how, would end the call. Anyone has an idea how I could do that ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for 3rd party applications to forcefully end a phone call on Windows Phone.